# AngularJS dynamic templates not loading correctly

Tags: angularjs

I have set up an application so that based on the device that is being used it will attempt to load template.device.html, if that fails than it will default to loading template.html. However I am having an issue, if I hit the page with the route included in the URL then the template will not load, however if I hit the page with no route provided and the application uses the $routeProvider.otherwise redirect(?) then it loads the correct route. Any ideas on what might be happening here that this only works if I hit the .otherwise in the route?

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  // Routes are provided in the routes array and then we test if there is a device specific templete for the route and will load.
  // If there is no device template the code will use the default template
  var routes = ['partial1','partial2'];
  angular.forEach(routes, function(route, key) {
    var defaultUrl = 'partials/' + route + '.html',
        deviceUrl = 'partials/' + route + '.' + getDevice() + '.html',
        initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']),
        $http = initInjector.get('$http');
    $http.get(deviceUrl).
      success(function() {
        setRouteProvider($routeProvider, deviceUrl, route);
      }).
      error(function(){
        setRouteProvider($routeProvider, defaultUrl, route);
      });
  });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/' + routes[0]});
}]);

function setRouteProvider($routeProvider, url, route) {
  // The controller name will be the route with the first letter capitalized and Ctrl appended to the end. i.e. RouteCtrl.
  $routeProvider.when('/' + route, {templateUrl: url, controller: route.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + route.substring(1) + 'Ctrl'});
}
```

Comment: What happens when "the template will not load"?  Do you get an error?  A 404?

Comment: @efarley both the `success` and `error` methods of `$http` are called asynchronously, thus your `setRouteProvider` function is called later, meaning that your expected route behaviour should work some time later too. Don't expect routing to block until `$http` completes, because it won't, which is why you see your problem.